# How can we improve error in decision-making by applying conditioning on floating-point numbers?

Tags: floating-point-precision

I am working with floating point arithmetic that involves decision making by the use of conditioning such as if...else etc. The algorithm works fine but I doubt that it's not been optimized to get the best results. I want to know that how can I improve the numerical stability by reducing the error in floating point numbers during comparison. I'm using C language in my project. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need better precision than one of the built in floating point standards, then a third party library or creating your own number system are about the only options. [GNU Multiple Precision](https://gmplib.org/), is an option.